# "progressively" load video in NextJS (from DatoCMS/mux)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-video

I'm using [DatoCMS](https://www.datocms.com) and NextJS to build a website. DatoCMS uses [Mux](https://www.mux.com) behind the scenes to process the video.

The video that comes through is fairly well optimised for whatever browser is being used, and potentially for ABR with HLS; however, it still can take a fair bit of time on the initial load.

The JSON from Dato includes some potentially useful other things:

```
  "video": {
      "mp4Url": "https://stream.mux.com/6V48g3boltSf5uQRB8HnelvtPglzZzYu/medium.mp4",
      "streamingUrl": "https://stream.mux.com/6V48g3boltSf5uQRB8HnelvtPglzZzYu.m3u8",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://image.mux.com/6V48g3boltSf5uQRB8HnelvtPglzZzYu/thumbnail.jpg"
    },
    "id": "44785585",
    "blurUpThumb": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHBwgHBhUICAgLCgoXDhgVDhkNDh0VGhUeFxUZHSIfGxUmKzcjHh0oHRwWJDUlKDkvMjIyGSI4PTcwPCsxMi8BCgsLDg0OHBAQHDsoIig7NTs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ly8vOzs1Ozs7Ozs7Ozs1NTU7Ozs1Ozs7OzUvLzsvLy8vLy8vL//AABEIAA8AGAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAYAAACAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQACBv/EAB4QAAICAgIDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECABEEBQMGEiIy/8QAFwEAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMFAP/EABsRAAIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAAMRIUEE/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDIYui48Y+saphApUQL2ZHNeJELTfALdGE943pl2m+gDFPJfP0qc/1JAMntKA0FYyTC9vIt2+JzrZP/2Q=="
  }
```

With either `next/image`, or the more proprietary [`react-datocms/image`](https://github.com/datocms/react-datocms/blob/master/docs/image.md), that `blurUpThumb` could be used as a placeholder while the full image is being loaded in the background, to improve UX, and (I believe) page-load speed / time to interactive.

Is there a way to achieve that same effect with the video instead of a file?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way an ABR, HLS or DASH etc, video can start faster is by starting with one of the lower resolutions and stepping up to a higher resolution after the first couple of segments once the video is playing and there is more time to buffer.

However in your case, the example video is very short, 13 seconds so the effect is pretty minimal. Playing it on Safari on a MAC I saw the step happen at 4 seconds which is almost a 3rd through already in this case.

Short of re-encoding with lower resolution or some special codecs I think you may find this hard to beat - Mux is a pretty mature video streaming service.

The direct links to the videos above loaded and played quite quickly for me, even over a relatively low speed internet. It might be worth looking at what else your page is loading at the same time as this may be competing for bandwidth and slowing things down.